# Google cloud vision, lumping lines together

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I'm testing Google cloud vision. I want it to just read across the page in sequence, line by line.
Here is the code.

```
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1633917/000163391720000091/q120paypalearningsreleas013.jpg'

def detect_text_uri(uri):
    """Detects text in the file located in Google Cloud Storage or on the Web.
    """
    from google.cloud import vision
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = vision.types.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = uri

    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    print('Texts:')

    for text in texts:
        print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

        vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                    for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

        print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))

    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))

if __name__ == '__main__': detect_text_uri(url)
```

You can see it does pretty well until it gets to "Payment Transactions per active acount", then it lumps it with the next line. It's no longer going line by line.

How do I fix this? The problem is when I look through the docs, I'm already using the text detection feature. Not sure how to further improve the result.

Comment: _How do I fix this?_ https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ _You can see it does pretty well until it gets to "Payment Transactions per active acount", then it lumps it with the next line._ How can we see that? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Yeah, I don't see "Payment Transactions per active account" anywhere in the code.

Comment: I get `This API method requires billing to be enabled. Please enable billing on project by visiting [link] then retry. ` Is there a free way to test your code?

Comment: Hey Matthew. it's actually free, because you get i like something like 4k images a month, but you have to have billing enabled.

Comment: Can you post the JSON response ?

Comment: @zeterain it's from the image

Comment: Oh gotcha. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The response is really really long.

Comment: Have you tried DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION instead TEXT_DETECTION?

Comment: @inga890. Yeah, it actually gets worse. It starts lumping very early on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google vision is not configurable in this levels.

You have two options to read text in document

**TEXT_DETECTION**  Run text detection / optical character recognition (OCR). Text detection is optimized for areas of text within a larger image; if the image is a document, use DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION instead.

**DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION** Run dense text document OCR. Takes precedence when both DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION and TEXT_DETECTION are present.

If TEXT_DETECTION and DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION return the same unsatisfying answer you have to modify the image itself.

For example using the [Cloud demo api](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) you can see immediate results

I slightly changed the image and got better results for this specific line.

[Img](https://ibb.co/gvS5Frp)
(cropped and with additional contrast)
[result](https://ibb.co/Bt2Xtgq)

Keep in mind it's just an example and you need to find a sufficient way to modify the image

**EDIT**:
also maybe it worth to explore [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/document-ai)

Comment: this is the unfortunate answer i was looking for. probably will have to wait for v2.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct but I wanted to point out [Document AI Table Parsing](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-tables) [beta] is the solution you want.

Table parsing will read your table and give you the proper line breaks. I used the [demo](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/drag-and-drop) with your photo and it read the table out correctly with no errors. It requires a PDF in the demo but will take a JPG directly via the API.

For the best results, also provide the table bounding polygon, but in most cases it will figure it out anyway:

> bounding-poly (optional): A bounding box hint for a table on the page.
> This field is intended for complex cases when the model may have difficulty locating the table. The values must be normalized `[0,1]`. Object format:
>
> ```
> {"x": X_MIN,"y": Y_MIN}, {"x": X_MAX,"y": Y_MIN},{"x": X_MAX,"y": Y_MAX},{"x": X_MIN,"y": Y_MAX}
> ```

Note: Document AI was mentioned in the other answer as well as an edit.

Comment: The demo has a UI, just click and upload your file (as a PDF) and it will show you the results visually. If you click the top link there is a code sample that you can easily use as well -- you can skip the bounding poly parts for a first go.

Comment: Is there a way to just give it a local file? like in this page https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr. In the samples, the file seems to come from a storage container in the cloud.

Comment: @jason as of now no, you must put it in Cloud Storage first.

Comment: FYI, Document AI has an actively monitored tag [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)

---

And Document AI does support local input using Online Processing. Follow this documentation for more information.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request